# Rewrite Route in middleware after Endpoint got matched

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am currently writing a rate-limiter with the help of a middleware, this is based on an per-user basis. When the rate-limit exceeds for a user, I want to rewrite the route to my 429 page which tells the use that he exceeded the rate-limit.

This is an example of what my current middle-ware looks like:

```cs
public class RateLimitMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if(RateLimitExceeded(context.User))
        {
            context.Request.Path = "/Home/Ratelimit";
        }

        return next.Invoke(context);
    }

    public bool RateLimitExceeded(ClaimsPrincipal user) 
    { 
        //...
    }
}
```

Now to my Configure method:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseRateLimit(); // This adds the RateLimitMiddleware class to the middlewares.

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

---

Now to the actual problem, you can't rewrite the route in any middleware after the `UseRouting`. Since it is the actual method deciding which Endpoint to pick. Therefore, is it possible to rewrite the route afterwards?

However, please do note, that I don't want to redirect the user to the rate-limit view. Additionally, I can't just move the middleware up in the chain, since I need the `HttpContext.User` to be set.